Extended Hidden Markov Models (HMM) parameter estimation
For simpler HMMs, we can use algorithms like Viterbi training (not decoding) or Baum Welch to estimate the parameters that best describe the observed data.
How do we do the same when using a more complex multivariate HMM or a second order HMM? Is there a resource I can use to see how the algorithms and the setup are adjusted in these cases? If there is pseudocode for them as opposed to a description that would be even better, although I understand that earlier algorithms like forward and backward would change too.
EDIT:
To the person who closed this question, it is not about programming/code debugging as you said, it is about statistics and algorithms.
